# Display Custom Text if date_picker date is expired

Tags: wp-admin

I am having a really hard time with these 2 small issues, I hope you will help me with some code.

I am using Advanced custom fields pro wordpress plugin.

1. I have a date picker field name "date_picker" , I want to display a custom text "Deal Expired" when the date is passed, so instead of it displaying the date it should replace it with the custom text when date is passed.

I have also tried the following code in functions.php, but gives me error.

```
$currentdate = new DateTime();
$date = get_field('date_picker', false, false);
$date = new DateTime($date);
if ($currentdate > $date) {
  echo '(Deal Expired)';  
} else {
  echo get_field( 'date_picker' );
}
```

2. One more issue is I have added custom text area to categories, but I want to display only those text area fields on category front-end page which has some text/date/content in them.

Comment: What error do you get? In which format do you get the date from the `get_field` function? Did you look at the documentation for how to convert the value to a DateTime object? https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-picker/ Please provide more details about what you have tried, what error you get, etc.

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error message : Notice: Function acf_get_value was called incorrectly. Advanced Custom Fields PRO - We've detected one or more calls to retrieve ACF field values before ACF has been initialized. This is not supported and can result in malformed or missing data.

Comment: In which hook or function did you place your code? Seems like you are trying to execute this code too early.

Answer (score 0):

If you've dropped it right into `functions.php` and not inside an action hook, the code is running before ACF has initialized. Try running on `acf/init` action (untested):

```php
add_action( 'acf/init', static function () {
    $currentdate = new DateTime();

    $date = get_field( 'date_picker', false, false );
    $date = new DateTime( $date );

    if ( $currentdate > $date ) {
      echo '(Deal Expired)';  
    } else {
      echo get_field( 'date_picker' );
    }
} );
```